# What is the best way to maintain images in database which should help in faster retrieval of images

Tags: image, performance, azure-blob-storage

We have an app which displays the product images. Storing it in azure blob storage will be faster in retrieval or storing it in azure file storage? Are there any other better ways to store images which helps in faster retrieval. Please suggest !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally based on your requirement.

**Based on key features:**

- Azure blob mainly used for storing/retrieving static files.Blob storage is optimized for storing massive amounts of unstructured data(text or binary files).
- Azure File supports SMB and NFS protocol so that you could [mount
  Azure File share to your servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) to share files between servers.

**Based on cost:**

For storing/retrieving the same size files, Azure File will be more expensive than Azure Storage, for details, please see [Azure storage pricing sheet](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/).

**Based on performance and limits:**

please see [azure blob storage limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-blob-storage-limits) and [Azure File limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-files-limits)

So if your app just needs to store/retrieve static files from Azure storage, using Azure blob is recommended.